# creating an installer for mac osx

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I want to create an Installer for mac osx

It should do the following

1. Installing nodeJS if it isn't already
2. downloading a npm package
3. running an npm command

Is that possible and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it fits your workflow to package your application as an executable, rather than installing node and npm on the target machine? Then the node executable and the necessary npm modules are included in your package

If so, here are some executable generation packages for node:

https://github.com/areve/node2exe

https://github.com/nexe/nexe

http://enclosejs.com/

but my personal recommendation is pkg (I am in no way affiliated):

https://github.com/zeit/pkg

you can tell pkg to just make you a macos binary with the following flag: 
`--targets macos-x64`

one issue you may run into is that npm packages with compiled components require the  .node file of the compiled component (available in node_modules once it is built), but this .node file must be specific to the target platform, architecture, and the version of node that your code was compiled against. With pkg, you have to recreate the target environment, then build and save the . node file as part of your package (in the same path as the executable). pkg will tell you if this is going to be a problem

If you require further customisation of your osx software once you have baked-in node functionality you can use https://github.com/sveinbjornt/Platypus

Comment: thanks but that not exactly what I mean. I use this: https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier but when I run this application on a mac without nodejs and without calling `npm install nativefier -g` and without calling `nativefier "http://medium.com"` it does not work. 

So the application should be build via the installation process